# Scroll to top only if state is true

Tags: reactjs

I Want to scroll to top only if the state is true:

```js
 // switch topBar (show / hide )
  const [topBarOpen, setTopBarOpen] = useState(false)

  const handletopBar = () => {
    setTopBarOpen(prev => !prev)
  }

// this useEffect always scroll to top doesn't matter if is the the true or false when I click the "Switch" button

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  }, [handletopBar])
```

I'm using a switch buttom whit props "handletopBar":

```js
 <SwitchButtom handletopBar={handletopBar} />
```

Comment: `if (topBarOpen)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency in the useEffect should be `topBarOpen`. Check if it's `true` using a simple `if` statement.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(topBarOpen) {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  }
}, [topBarOpen])
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to understand the concept of dependencies in useeffect.